# Why I can not change html tag font from bold to normal?

Tags: phpstorm

In PhpStorm I have html file has this markup:

```
<p>hello</p>
```

The `hello` appear as bold and I tried from `File -> Settings` and in both `Language Defaults` and `HTML` to change the `Tag` value to be no bold but I found it in both already no bold !! So why it appear bold ??!! Any advises ?

[image]

Comment: Neither of those styles in `HTML` or `Language Defaults` affect **plain text** (the text content between HTML tags). You should check these styles instead (in this order): `HTML | HTML code`, `XML | Tag data` (most likely will be this one) and then `General | Text | Default text`.

Comment: it was `XML | Tag data` thanks alot. post it as an answer to select ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither of those styles (that you have tried already) in `HTML` or `Language Defaults` affect plain text (the text content between HTML tags).

You should check these styles instead (in this order):

- `HTML | HTML code`
- `XML | Tag data` (most likely will be this one)
- `General | Text | Default text` at the end (as it's the base for everything).